# Redirect URL problem in managed package

Tags: integration

I am facing some problem on managed package. I have integrate Salesforce with Google Drive my problem is that i have set Redirect URl on Google drive App now when I installed this package in my another org that time Redirect URl change because my org have a different base URL.

I am getting Redirect URL mismatch problem, How I can solve this problem in salesforce Any help will be very appreciable.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you using "managed release" or "managed beta"?

Comment: @Ravikant Did you find any solution for this? I am having the same problem with my managed package code.

Comment: @SagarThoriya have you found the solution?)

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup a new app in customer Google Account which will have

1. Redirect URL for customer Org
2. And a unique Client Id and Client secret.

   You should use these three things from custom setting, so that after installing the manged package and creating a new Google app, you can set those values to custom setting.

You create a installation documentation for the customers which can include these steps.

Thanks

Comment: I don't want to create a new application each time after installing package.

Comment: It is not a good Approach.

Comment: I want to use same approach like "Cirrus Files for Google Drive" app exchange product in which we don't need to set these value each time.

Comment: Best approach is to create a new app per org for security reasons. As no good company will allow your app to manage there google account.
If you really want to use only one app you can pass your org redirect url into state parameter of request and your registered redirect url will call complete the auth flow and will redirect the last response to state url.

Comment: Let me know if you need detail help in above approach.

Comment: Yes i want detail help in above approach, please give me so i can implement its thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the redirect url which you have registered is Google? Salesforce url or any other Url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33956/discussion-between-ravikant-kedia-and-sfdcgod).

Answer (score -1):

One of the approaches would be create 2 apps for production and sandbox environment and make redirect urls like this:

```
https://login.salesforce.com/apex/<package prefix>__<page name>
https://test.salesforce.com/apex/<package prefix>__<page name>
```

That would work for every production or sandbox org respectively.

You also need to make some logic in auth process to pick correct app during auth by checking if org is sandbox or not.

Comment: In Google app , You can add more then one redirect url.

Comment: If you will add above URL's mentioned by you,it will redirect you to login page.

Comment: @SFDCGOD those are working fine for me. Did you test that?

Comment: I have tried your solution and they did not work ,as whenever google redirect to login.salesforce.com, it opens login screen

Comment: We can add only 25 redirect url on google application, after this it will not work. so i think this approach is not good to achieve our task.

Comment: @RavikantKedia can you describe more about your scenario? Like what do you want to achieve and how oauth process happening?

Comment: @ravikant did you find the solution