# How do I authorize access to a managed application in another org?

Tags: managed-package, oauth2, authentication, connected-apps, authorization

I am working with a managed package that is installed in Org A.  The user wants to be able to access information from their other org, Org B, where this package is not installed.  The plan is to use web server oauth flow to grant access to the managed package and return the user to their originating org.

As a proof of concept I'm doing the following:

1. Log into Org A
2. Manually navigate to https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=[MyClientId]&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fna1.salesforce.com%2Fapex%2FExternalOAuthHandler
3. Log in to Org B and approve access to the connected app.
4. Grab the "code" parameter off of the query string and execute a POST request to get the access token and instance url for Org B.

Here's some sample code for what i'm posting for step 4 (demo only - no way would you put the client_id and secret here):

```
$.post("https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token", {
    data: {
        "grant_type": "authorization_code",
        "code": "[code from first request]",
        "client_id": "[MyClientId]",
        "secret": "[MySecret]",
        "redirect_uri", "https://na1.salesforce.com/apex/ExternalOAuthHandler"
    }
}).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

There are 2 issues I'm running into:

1. The callback url that I configure for my connected app will be in an unpredictable domain for each customer that wants to use this feature.  I won't know their instance and they could also have it installed in an org with My Domain enabled.  The callback url can't contain wildcards either.  If I use na1 for the domain, i.e. http://na1.salesforce.com/apex/ExternalOAuthHandler, then it will look for that page in Org B where it doesn't exist.  So using na1 is definitely not an option.  If I just pass whatever the originating host is and append "/apex/ExternalOAuthHandler", I receive a callback mismatch error because it will be unpredictable and won't match the configured callback url.  How can I resolve this?
2. Even though I don't redirect to the correct URI with the na1 url, I do still get the code on the query string and a page not found message in OrgB.  I can still grab that code and perform step 4 manually.  However, I receive the following response:

> {
>       "error": "invalid_client",
>       "error_description": "invalid client credentials" }

Why would I get invalid client credentials here?  Am I going about this the right way and missing something?

The tutorial I followed is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vlrK3YZ_Fj0.   However the difference with my scenario is that I'm getting this to work with a managed package installed in someone's org where the domain of the redirect URL is unpredictable.

Comment: For non-SF oAuth callback I set redirect URL to login.salesforce.com/apex/packagename__pagename. Problem is that in your case, both environments are salesforce, so it may happen then during authentication you get redirected to the same org, where you just got authorised. Similar problem is here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/104458/redirect-url-problem-in-managed-package/104463#104463

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just went through something similar where the final destination varied depending on the customer so a static callback int he code did not work.

What I did on our LMA org to handle this was:

1. Placed the connected app within the LMA org
2. Added a VF page and code to handle the callback on a force.com site
3. Added the URL of the callback on the connected app for the sites page

Then when doing the oAuth process I use the state parameter to define the final URL to return the user to with the encrypted session information. This final URL would be a VF page within your package or something else that you control as you have to pass the session information.

```
public class state{
    public boolean isSandbox;
    public string uri;

    public state(Boolean isSandbox, String URI){
        this.isSandbox = isSandbox; //Allows for test or login in my implementation. May or may not be needed for you
        this.URI = URI; //You will need to URL encode this
    }
}
```

I encrypt the JSON serialized auth response and put it in a parameter named `auth` the is returned to the final endpoint

```
public static String encryptString(String toEncryptString) {
    Blob encryptedData = Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV('AES128', EncodingUtil.base64Decode(keyHash), EncodingUtil.base64Decode(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(toEncryptString))));
    return EncodingUtil.urlEncode(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(encryptedData), 'UTF-8');
}
```

and the auth response class:

```
public class auth_response {

    @AuraEnabled public string refresh_token;
    @AuraEnabled public string access_token;
    @AuraEnabled public string instance_url;
    @AuraEnabled public string error_description;
    @AuraEnabled public string id;
    @AuraEnabled public string scope;
    @AuraEnabled public string token_type;

}
```

Your implementation will vary but the key is to use a known Callback and pass JSON'd State parameters that define the final endpoint. Then encrypt, url encode, etc the auth parameters and pass them to that final endpoint as a parameter.

The complete implementation is a bit much to post here. Maybe I will get around to writing a simple self contained example at some point.

**Note** Using heroku as a callback for the connected app may be prudent if you expect a lot of API calls.

Comment: Hey @Eric, thanks for the detailed response.  I'm close to marking this as the answer.. I'm doing something very similar.  I wrote a .net core service that is living in azure to handle this at the moment. However, I keep getting invalid_client_credentials when i request the access token with my authorization code.  did you ever run into that

Comment: Yes, and there could be many reasons. Check endpoint, your oAuth process, etc. It is best to get the basic oAuth process working then expand the logic as required. Makes it easier to troubleshoot when you have the basics working.

Comment: solved my issue with the invalid client credentials.  had a typo in the token request.  I'm now redirected to the URL of origin.  HOWEVER, one final problem.  I'm logged in on Org A, I call my service which redirects me to the SF login to approve the connected app.  I'm still logged in to Org A with that request.  so I click "not you" to log out of Org A and log in to Org B.  If I do that and approve the client, i'm redirected back to the originating url (in Org A), but now i am no longer signed in.  @Eric did you run into something like that as well?

Comment: technically my original question is answered, and i'll mark this as solved.

Comment: @Donuts - Yes. Since we are doing dev on the same browser we typicalyl run into these issues. End users will typically not run into them. to test the process use a broswer that you do not typically use and ensure all sessions have expired or clear the cache. That will give you a real example of what the user experiences so you can tell if you need to modify anything

Comment: I think this still applies to the prod user.  say i'm at na50.salesforce.com/mypackage.  User clicks a button "Add Org" which calls my web service, which redirects the user to https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize.  but they're already logged in with Org A credentials, and if my connected app already has been approved to Org A, they won't see the approve/deny options - it will just call back and finish the process but with tokens for Org A.

Comment: @Donuts - That is true. Unfortunately you are at the mercy of the design. With MyDomain this should not be as much of an issue but not everyone has migrated yet. Not sure of a way to get out of it unless you explicitly navigate to the logout.jsp page first. Would be a good new question though

Comment: Eric, did you pass AppExchange security Review with this design?

Answer (score 0):

Another possible approach might be to dynamically register an Connected App with a callback url for given subscriber.

There is a limit on the number of connected apps created per org (100).

If we anticipate having Z customers then we can created Y = [Z/100] connected apps in different orgs to get initial access token and then use this pool of initial access tokens to dynamically register connected apps with a callback url of Org A.